How to delete a code cleanup profile in Visual Studio Professional 2022
I have two code cleanup profiles in my code cleanup configuration.
I can change both of them, by adding or removing items it should clean up, but I can't seem te remove either of the profiles in 'Configure Code Cleanup'. No delete button, even tried to remove all items from a list, but it still wouldn't go away.
How can I remove one of these profiles?
Visual Studio version: 17.8.7
Best regards,
Vincent
Edit:
I wanted one of the profiles removed, because it looked like I had to select one of the profiles each time I wanted to clean my code.
Turns out this is not needed, so my need for removal of one of the profiles has gone.

That's not possible.  Use Help > Send Feedback if you see a practical benefit to managing profiles.

VS coming with 2 code cleanup profiles by default.This is by-design and you cannot remove them.
Feel free to submit a feature request at VS Developer Community to suggest adding the feature that meets your needs.
